# Scrolling vertically grid content

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, scrollbar, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone application.

I have a phone page with a big textblock and a picture inside on a stackpanel. Because the textblock is big the picture isn't visible. I set **VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"** on stackpanel but I can't see the picture.

How can I use a scrollbar to see the content bellow the textblock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your content in a `ScrollViewer` :

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <!-- Your content here -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: took me quite a few minutes to realize that VerticalScrollbarVisibility is not the same as VerticalScrollBarVisibility (the latter being correct)